# jsHint 2.9.3 error in WebStorm 11 'use esnext option'

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, jshint

[image]

This is still an unsolvable issue for me using WebStorm 11 and the latest version of JSHint 2.9.3

The problem is this:

If I specify only `"esversion": 6,` in my .jshintrc I get perfect JSHINT output. The problem is that the WebStorm editor is erroring out basic ES6 keywords like 'import'. It states I should use `'esnext: true'` See image.

If I add `'esnext: true'` in .jshintrc too then JSHint is complaining that "Incompatible values for the 'esversion' and 'esnext 0% scanned". So I can't use them combined.

If I only use `esnext: true` then I get the the same error 0% scanned. So whatever I do. I can't get it fixed.

I am not sure what exactly generates the warning and how to get rid of it using only `esversion: 6` and not the deprecated esnext.

Is it something in WebStorm? What JsHint is WebStorm using? Is it the one installed in my node_modules? Does it use a JShint built-in WebStorm or a plugin? How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this checking other issues posted and links in it.

Like this one

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/jshint.html

In the settings of Webstorm I updated my version to 2.9.3 in the Version dropdown. See the picture.

[image]